# What is the difference between the vectorization of icc and that of ispc?

Tags: vectorization, intel, icc, ispc

Both Intel C/C++ Compiler and Intel SPMD Program Compiler can generate vectorized code. My question is, is there any possible reason I should use ispc for code vectorization provided that my icc also can generate vectorized code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, While Intel C Compiler / C++ Compiler discriminate towards Intel made CPU's the ISPC is not (I think it can also generate ARM code).

So yes, if you're having hard time with ICC CPU dispatcher on AMD CPU's you should use ISPC.